# Logs from GCF in Go doesn't contains log level

Tags: go, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-logging

I am trying send info/error logs to StackDriver Logging on GCP from Cloud Function written in Go, however all logs dosen't have log level assignment.

I have created function from https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/blob/master/functions/helloworld/hello_logging.go
to demonstrate problem.

[image: link to image with logs]

Answer (score 2):

Cloud Support here! What you are trying to do is not possible, as specified in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#functions-log-helloworld-go):

> - Logs to **stdout** or **stderr** do not have an associated log level.
> - Internal system messages have the **DEBUG** log level.

What you probably need is to use [Logging API](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/logging), specifically the [Log Levels](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/logging#hdr-Log_Levels) section.

If this is not working for you either you could try using `node.js` instead of `go` as it [currently emits logs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#functions-log-helloworld-nodejs) to `INFO` and `ERROR` levels using `console.log()` and `console.error()` respectively.

Comment: I have tried using that library but I cannot get it working. It doesn't returned any errors but nothing is logged to stackdriver.

Comment: Hello @nephe I have modified my answer with another possible solution for you. i would also like you to run this command: `gcloud functions logs read FUNCTION_NAME`, and verify if you can see the logs in there.

Comment: I have tried and it also returns logs without any level, only the ones produced by standard logger, not the one that you have lined. Can you link me to issue where I can monitor when this kind of support will be added to GCF in Go?

Comment: I have found [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/124403972) public issue requesting the implementation of logging severity for GCF in general. In addition, I've created [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/139174817) issue requesting logging severity for GCF in Go specifically.

Answer (score 2):

I created a package to do exactly this:
[`github.com/ncruces/go-gcp/glog`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/ncruces/go-gcp/glog)

It works on App Engine, Kubernetes Engine, Cloud Run, and Cloud Functions. Supports setting logging levels, request/tracing metadata, and structured logging.

Usage:

```
func HelloWorld(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    glog.Infoln("Hello logs")
    glog.Errorln("Hello logs")
    // or, to set request metadata:
    logger := glog.ForRequest(r)
    logger.Infoln("Hello logs")
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks that it is working properly and it is setting valid error levels.

Comment: Hi, I would like to know what permissions should I give my functions so they can use the API. I'm currently receiving an permission error while trying to use in my code

Comment: Hi can you please answer this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72504886/why-google-logging-client-libraries-not-logging-inside-google-cloud-functions

Comment: No, sorry. My package deliberately avoids using the logging client, instead logging to stdout/err.

Answer (score 1):

you can use external library which allow you to set the log level. [Here](https://github.com/guillaumeblaquiere/bqToFtp/blob/master/BqToFtp.go) an example of what I use.
Use logrus for setting the minimal log level (you can improve this code by providing log level in env var) and joonix for fluentd formatter.(line 25)

A point of attention. Line 11, I rename the logrus package log
`log "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"`
Thus, don't use log standard library, but logrus library. It's sometime boring... you can simply replace log by logrus for avoiding all confusion.

Joonix is a fluentD formatter for transforming the logs into an ingestable format for Stackdriver.

Comment: I have tried with formatter that you have provided but it still behaves in invalid way. 
Everything is added as text payload `textPayload:  "{"httpRequest":{"requestMethod":"POST","status":200,"responseSize":"31337","userAgent":"Go-http-client/1.1","latency":{"nanos":123000000}},"message":"additional info","severity":"INFO","timestamp":{"seconds":1565175967,"nanos":261743604}}" `

Comment: Yes, there is a tricky thing. Look at the line 11
`log "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"`
I rename the logrus package to log. Then I use log.debugf(...) for logging in debug level.
The formater only transform the output in fluentD format, for an understable ingestion by stackdriver.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you. I am using los as `github.com/sirupsen/logrus`.
Then I set formatter as `joonix` and set level as `Debug`. However it still results as text payload in stackdriver.

Comment: You are right. This works on Cloud Run and GCE/GKE but not on Cloud Function. I performed some tests with different logger configuration. I don't understand what is different and why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I, too, took a stab at creating a package for this.  If you use logrus (https://github.com/sirupsen/logrus), then this may be helpful:

https://github.com/tekkamanendless/gcfhook

I'm using this in production, and it's working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the https://github.com/apsystole/log. It's also log- and logrus-compatible, but a small **zero-dependency** module unlike the libraries used in two existing answers which bring 400+ modules as their dependencies (gasp... I am simply looking at `go mod graph`).